# How can I add an x label to this subplot that spans my total x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

How can I add an X label that spans my 2 subplots? Secondly, how can I adjust my X axis index using subplots b/c xticks or set_xticklabels doesn't seem to display properly? I can provide data sets, if it helps. I thought I used the subplot command properly.

[image: Example of current final figure.]

```
x1 = np.r_[50:64]
x2 = np.r_[89:103]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

#Left plot
ax1.plot(x1,left[0],color='red',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV Ca$^{2+}$',linestyle='dashed',markersize=6)
ax1.plot(x1,left[1],color='blue',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV Mg$^{2+}$',linestyle='dashed',markersize=6)
ax1.plot(x1,left[2],color='red',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV S55D/E59D Ca$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='6',markersize=10)
ax1.plot(x1,left[3],color='blue',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV S55D/E59D Mg$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='6',markersize=10)
ax1.plot(x1,left[4],color='red',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV D94S/G98E Ca$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='1',markersize=6)
ax1.plot(x1,left[5],color='blue',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV D94S/G98E Mg$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='1',markersize=6)
#Right plot
ax2.plot(x2,right[0],color='red',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV Ca$^{2+}$',linestyle='dashed',markersize=6)
ax2.plot(x2,right[1],color='blue',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV Mg$^{2+}$',linestyle='dashed',markersize=6)
ax2.plot(x2,right[2],color='red',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV S55D/E59D Ca$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='6',markersize=10)
ax2.plot(x2,right[3],color='blue',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV S55D/E59D Mg$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='6',markersize=10)
ax2.plot(x2,right[4],color='red',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV D94S/G98E Ca$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='1',markersize=6)
ax2.plot(x2,right[5],color='blue',marker="o",label=r'$\alpha$PV D94S/G98E Mg$^{2+}$',linestyle='solid',linewidth='1',markersize=6)


ax1.legend(fontsize=14,handlelength=2,loc="best")
ax1.set_ylabel('Contribution Energy (kcal/mol)', fontsize=25)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=28, length=9, width=4)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=28, length=9, width=4)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.suptitle('\u03B1PV WT and Mutants',fontsize=35)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use x parameter when setting up the xlabel. Here is an example:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 1])
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
ax.plot(data,data)
ax2.plot(data,data)
ax.set_xlabel("xLabelAcrossTwoSubPlot",x=1.1,fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Also if you want to control the ticks explicitly here is how to do it:

```
### control ticks
ts = data[:]
ax.set_xticks(ts)
ax.set_xticklabels([ '#%d'%k for k in ts])
```